# Setting Shop thumbnail images in Woocommerce in Wordpress

Tags: image, woocommerce

How do I set a different image for the shop thumbnails for Woocommerce in Wordpress?

I tried it using the content in CSS but the slide cart images and the cart page are not changing.

Answer (score 1):

Place this code in your functions.php file.  It will modify all the shop catalog images to whatever new URL you override the images with.

```
function modify_woocommerce_product_get_image( $image, $product, $size, $attr, $placeholder ) {
    if( $size = 'shop_catalog' )
        return '<img src="">';

    return $image;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_image', 'modify_woocommerce_product_get_image', 10, 5 );
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible I can use this to assign different images for each product?

Comment: Yes, you can check the $size variable for the type of image it is ie single product and add in another if statement.

Comment: I tried using if else statements but the mini cart and cart items do not reflect the image I set.

 if( $size = 'shop' || is_shop() || is_cart() || is_checkout() ) {
     if ($product_id == 1297) {
         return '<img src="">';
     }